# Finding the times when particles with positions $6\cos(2\pi t)\hat{i}+6\sin(2\pi t)\hat{j}$ and $-6\sin(2\pi t)\hat{i}-6\cos(2\pi t)\hat{j}$ meet

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

> The 2 particles describe circular movements, with these equations of position:
>
> $$\begin{align}
> \vec{r_1}&=\phantom{-}6\cos(2\pi t)\hat{i}+6\sin(2\pi t)\hat{j} \\
> \vec{r_2}&=-6\sin(2\pi t)\hat{i}-6\cos(2\pi t)\hat{j}
> \end{align}$$
> Find the 2 positions where both meet, and the first 2 times where they do it.

So this isn't a doubt about the problem, but rather about if they do really meet, i'm discussing this with one friend of mine, what we did was: Equated both vectors and after simplifying a little bit we got to $$\cos(2\pi t)=-\sin(2\pi t)$$ which answers are $$t=\frac38$$ and $$t=\frac78$$ is this correct or has the teacher messed up and there is not any meeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the unit circle definition, $$cos(\eta)=-sin(\eta)$$ whenever $$\eta = \frac {3\pi}4+n\pi$$ for $n\in \mathcal N$(natural numbers, in case you didn't know). Therefore, solving the equation $$2\pi t=\frac {3\pi}4 +n\pi$$ we get$$t=\frac 38 +\frac n2$$ for $n =1,2,3,...$.
So, yes, you are right, but not entirely, there are infinitely many solutions for $t$ corresponding to every natural number. But, if you want to know if they really meet, then all you must do is simply solve the equation, if the equation does not give you a contradiction (i.e., 1=2, etc.) then you must plug the value you get back into the original equation and see if you get the right values. For $-\sin$ and $\cos$ particularly, they do intersect infinitely often.

Comment: wait isn't sine and cosine's period 2pi? if so why you do n times pi instead of 2n times pi?

Comment: Look at the unit circle, for $n=1$, we have $\frac {7\pi}8$ in which case $\cos (\frac{7\pi}8)= \frac {\sqrt2}2$ and $\sin(\frac {7\pi}8)=-\frac{\sqrt2}2$ when the angle is $\frac{3\pi}4$, the sign is switched.

Comment: what does the sign has to do with adding pi times n instead of 2pi times n? i don't get what that has to do with my q

Comment: Do you not know the unit circle? I answered your question in that the functions intersect infinitely often because they have opposite signs at the particular angles I listed. This has nothing to do with the period of sine and cosine but it has to do with particular values based on the unit circle definition.

Comment: oh i see now i think, though i've always thought of the adding pi times n (on this case), n in Z, was due to the period, but i guess not? so whenever wanting all the solutions of a trig equation, should I always add +pi n, n in Z, on the cases of cos and sin?